# Співробітничати чи співпрацювати? Чи можна вживати обидва слова?

Tags: вживання-слів

Давно цікавило запитання чи правильно говорити *"співробітничати"*, бо, як на мене, це звучить трохи кострубато. Однак якщо вдатись до семантики- то говорять "йду на роботу", а не "на працю". Але іменник краще підходить "працівник", а не "робітник".  В Академічному словнику є слово [*співробітничати*](http://sum.in.ua/s/spivrobitnychaty) та [*співпрацювати*](http://sum.in.ua/s/spivpracjuvaty). Хоча на багатьох сайтах, наприклад [Online Corrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8/), пишуть, що правильно лише "співпрацювати".

То чи мають право на існування обидва варіанти чи краще все-таки вживати *"співпрацювати"*?

Comment: Поправив форматування. Зазирніть, будь ласка, всередину, щоб побачити, як робити посилання. Якщо щось не так, то завжди можна поправити, натиснувши [edit].

Comment: Питання з розділу "Coworker or cojobber?". Робота та праця дещо різні речі, звідци й різниця між співробітничати чи співпрацювати. Особисто я вважаю співпрацювати - єдиний правильний варіянт, бо воно окреслює акт, процес виконання праці cпільно, а не спільну роботу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всюди знаходила одну і ту ж інформацію, що все-таки правильні обидва варіанти.
Наприклад, [Офіційний сайт Української мови](http://ukrainskamova.com/search/?q=%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8&t=0) пише:

СПІВПРАЦЮВАТИ

Синоніми до слова СПІВПРАЦЮВАТИ : співробітничати; (з ворогом) коляборувати; п к ЮЮЧИЙ, що співпрацює, залучений до співпраці, співробітник, неґ. коляборант, о. у співпраці.

Щодо того, чи говорять "йду на працю", то так, Ви маєте рацію, не користуються таким терміном, але ж є подібний навіть у діалектах "йду до праці", що походить з польської мови ["pracować"](https://sjp.pwn.pl/slowniki/pracowa%C4%87.html) (Брала зі [Словника польської мови](https://sjp.pwn.pl/slowniki/pracowa%C4%87.html)).

В [Українському тлумачному словнику](https://ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru/169241) подають, що:

співробітничати
    -аю, -аєш, недок.
    1) Займатися якоюсь діяльністю, працювати разом із ким-небудь.
    2) Бути співробітником якої-небудь установи. || Брати участь як автор у роботі якогось друкованого органу.

Щодо сайту [Online Corrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8/), то там написано, що лише "не рекомендується" і що можна замінити на "кращий варіант". Про заборону вживати там не йдеться.

З Вашого дозволу і свою думку висловлю. Абсолютно погоджуюсь з [Online Corrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8/), бо, як на мене, добряче "ріже вухо" варіант "співробітничати". Якщо ж є можливість замінити його, то все ж краще дослухатися, "співпрацювати" звучить значно краще.